# Sumar dos variables en Ensamblador MASM

Tags: ensamblador, programación-bajo-nivel, masm

Tengo una duda sobre la suma en registros para Ensamblador MASM

```
 TITLE Suma variables
 INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
 .data
 a dword 10000h
 b dword 40000h
 valorFinal dword ?
.code
 main PROC
       mov eax,a ; empieza con 10000h
       add eax,b ; suma 40000h
       mov valorFinal,eax ; 
      call DumpRegs
      exit
 main ENDP
 END main
```

Mi duda es cuando yo uso `add` con `b`, estoy añadiendo solo el valor de la variable, o estoy añadiendo el valor y la dirección en memoria, porque tengo entendido que para obtener el valor en concreto se debe encerrar entre `[]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En MASM (y TASM en modo compatible con MASM), cuando escribes:

```
a dword 10000h
b dword 40000h
```

`a` y `b` son etiquetas que representan la dirección del almacenamiento asignado a las dobles palabras `10000h` y `40000h` respectivamente.

Cuando se usa una etiqueta como operando, MASM sabe que esa etiqueta representa una dirección de memoria, y decide que el parámetro es una referencia a memoria. Para forzar a que se use la dirección de memoria como un valor inmediato, se puede utilizar `OFFSET` precediendo a la etiqueta. Resumiendo:

```
mov eax, a          ; mueve 10000h a eax
mov eax, OFFSET a   ; mueve la dirección donde está 10000h a eax
mov eax, [a]        ; en MASM equivale a MOV eax, a
```

En cambio, cuando se escribe:

```
foo EQU 42
bar EQU 66
```

`foo` y `bar` son constantes simbólicas que representan 42 y 66, y no se reserva espacio para 42 y 66. Al utilizar una constante simbólica como parámetro, MASM trata el parámetro como un valor inmediato.

```
mov eax, foo        ; mueve 42 a eax
```

---

El hecho de que el significado de una instrucción sea diferente dependiendo de si sus parámetros son etiquetas o constantes puede resultar confuso. Otros ensambladores, como NASM (también Yasm, que usa la sintaxis de NASM), TASM en modo IDEAL, o fasm, requieren que se usen corchetes para tratar un parámetro como una referencia a memoria, y si no hay corchetes siempre tratan el parámetro como un valor inmediato.

Comment: tu respuesta y la de @Konamiman son contradictorias. ¿quién tiene razón?

Answer (score 8):

Con la instrucción `a dword 10000h` estás definiendo una zona de memoria de 4 bytes que contiene el valor 10000h, en este caso `a` se refiere a la dirección de esa zona de la memoria (que será la que el compilador decida) y con `mov eax,a` está cargando en el acumulador la dirección de memoria, **no** el contenido de la memoria.

Por tu pregunta no queda claro qué es lo que quieres conseguir, pero probablemente será una de estas dos cosas:

1. Cargar el acumulador con el valor almacenado en la zona de memoria definida por `a` (es decir, hacer que el procesador lea 4 bytes a partir de `a` y almacene el resultado en `eax`). En ese caso debes usar `mov eax,[a]`.
2. Definir `a` como una constante, que será sustituida directamente por el valor correspondiente en tiempo de compilación. En ese caso debes definir la constante como `a equ 10000h` (no uses `dword`). El código compilado será entonces equivalente a `mov eax,10000h`.

Y lo mismo se aplica a la instrucción `add`.